# How to insert a constant value into a column using ASP.Net SqlBulkCopy

Tags: asp.net, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

In the below code, I am trying insert the records from excel to Database table, but an additional column is not passed through the excel, which has to be populated with a constant value(foreach loop with a different value) assigned from the requested page.

```
string CONSTANTVALUE="Test";
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "TABLE NAME";
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("TABLECOLUMN1", "EXCELCOLUMN1");
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("TABLECOLUMN2", "EXCELCOLUMN2");
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("TABLECOLUMN3", CONSTANTVALUE);
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
```

But the code doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume your `dr` is a reader of some kind.  How is it populated?  It may be possible to select a default value into a column and map *that*.  Something like this (sql syntax)

```
select 
    EXCELCOLUMN1, 
    EXCELCOLUMN2, 
    'ConstantValueFromPage' as EXCELCUSTOM 
from 
    sheet1
```

Then have:

```
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("TABLECOLUMN3", "EXCELCUSTOM");
```

HTH

Comment: Imagine the default value is a very long string. Will the redundantly per row reoccurring default value be optimized away in the transport data structures (Oracle or SqlServer drivers) and in the ADO.NET DataTable for e.g?

Answer (score 6):

You can do it, by changing your command text. As below

```
string CONSTANTVALUE="Test";
OleDbCommand command=new OleDbCommand("select *,"+CONSTANTVALUE+" as [ConstantCol] from [sheet$]",ObleDbCon);
using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
{
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "TABLE NAME";
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("TABLECOLUMN1", "EXCELCOLUMN1");
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("TABLECOLUMN2", "EXCELCOLUMN2");
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("TABLECOLUMN3", "ConstantCol");
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
}
```

Comment: This code worked great for me, but two notes: 1) The parameters for ColumnMappings.Add are (sourceColumn, destinationColumn).  So if you are trying to copy from Excel to a database table, then the arguments should be reversed, it should be bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("EXCELCOLUMN1", "TABLECOLUMN1"); 2) if you are going to use column names for Excel, then your Excel connection string needs to include HDR=Yes.  If found it easier to use indices so that I don't have to rely on the person making the spreadsheet to use the right header names.  THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting a default value for you column in database? I think it's the most easiest way, as after inserting any record, the default value would also get inserted into the specified column (it acts like triggers).

Comment: As per the question, I think the constant value might differ for each request. how can you set the default value?

Comment: In that case, I think you can use SMO (server management objects, the API to work with SQL Server in code) to change the default value of the column, before inserting new records.